# SQL QUERY on a comma separated TEXT field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sorry for the incomplete title - I need a point in the right direction on this one too.
I'm trying to write a query for searching records that contain strings in a comma separated text field. I use MySql and php.

Records example:

```
recordID | statuses[TEXT]
1010     | 102
1011     | 100,103
1012     | 100,106,201,300
```

I query statues that I want to search for from another table statues_dataset

```
statusName | statusCode | Yes/No
name1      | 100        |   
name2      | 101        |
name3      | 102        |  Yes
name3      | 103        |
name4      | 106        |  Yes
```

Now I would like to find all records that contain statues 102 OR 106

I can solve this in two steps
query statues_dataset for ones I want and then concat the condition part so I basically get the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t
WHERE t.statuses LIKE '%201%'
OR t.statuses LIKE '%206%'
```

OR this one

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('201',t.statuses)
OR FIND_IN_SET('206',t.statuses)
```

I would get the result I want:

```
    recordID | statuses
    1010     | 102
    1012     | 100,106,201,300
```

Now I was wondering if there is a better way to solve this. Preferably in one query.
Or in two queries where i would create a list of values I want to searh for. 
I looked at FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist) function, but the problem is I need multiple str.
Is there a function I can use so I can fill it with multiple values I want to search for?
I've been googling but I'm afraid I don't know how to properly ask.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated lists in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just read your post again, and you say "or" not "and".  The following query finds the records you are looking for:

```
select distinct r.*
from records r join
     statuses_dataset d
     on concat(',', r.statuses, ',') like concat('%,', d.status, ',%') and
        d.use = 'Yes'
```

I changed the like to include commas before and after the statuses string.  This allows the query to search for ",105," instead of "105", to prevent matching "1050" and so on.

If you change your mind and want records that have all the statuses, then the query is a little more complicated.  Here, the subquery *matches* first finds all records with any match on the codes.  It then counts the number of matches and returns the records that match all individual codes.

```
with matches as (select r.RecordId, count(distinct d.statuscode) as num_matches
                 from records r join
                      statuses_dataset d
                      on concat(',', r.statuses, ',') like concat('%,', d.status, ',%') and
                         d.use = 'Yes'
                 group by r.RecordId
                )
select r.*
from records r cross join
     (select count(distinct d.statuscode) as numyes
      from statuses_dataset
      where d.use = 'Yes'
     ) ssum join
     matches m
     on r.RecordId = m.Recordid and
        m.nummatches = ssum.numyes
```

Using of count distinct instead of count(*) just handles duplicates in the statuses table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I must admit I'll need some time to test it. If I understood you suggest I create a join on all values in statuses filed in myTable To table_statuses using concat?

Comment: at Gordon Linoff
Thank you. I tryed it out and it works like a charm. 
Bagon Igor

Answer (score 0):

I think you would better normalize your DB schema (when it's not too late), and store rows like `ID, recordID, status`, one row for one recordID-status relation. This would let you to filter your statuses by simple (and more efficient) `WHERE status in (X, Y, Z)` clause. Do not forget to index `recordID` and `status` fields indeed.

It should be quite straight-forward to convert your current dataset to normalized state, by some one-off script run.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood right. You suggest that I add fields with statues to myTable? or rather create a relationships?
I'm not the autor of myTable - I can only do SELECT queries from it. Statuses table has some 400 rows (actualy 400 tests for violations that were performed on MyTable) I think adding another field to myTable is not really an option since it has 41 fields already (and that is as broken down as possible)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function

```
SELECT recordID ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(statuses)
       FROM MyTable
       GROUP BY recordID ;
```

Comment: @p.cambpbell
I got the answer from Gordon Linoff, but I am intrigued how GROUP_CONCAT() might be used? As I understand it would give me All values I'm searching for, concatenated together "xx,xy,yy,.."